# Basic Mathematics

Tags: percentages

Thanks for your help.  I'm not too sure if this is the correct way to answer this question, but let me know!

A student is having issues with an online computing grading system.
The system is displaying his term grade, but not his actual test result.
The term grade was at 0.00% yesterday, until today when it was 12%  - the 12% is from the test which he sat recently, and the ONLY test he sat this term.

If the test he sat recently was weighted at 20% of term grade, and the mark displayed was 12% (due to the mark being 20%), what is his final mark for the first test?  REMEMBER - he has not sat any other tests yet, but the mark displayed is **worth 20%**

---

From my understanding it's simply just 12*5 = 60% ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let's approach it in a different way-

He got $12$ marks out of $100$.

That $100$ was $20\%$ of $500$

So, he got $12*5=60$ marks out of $500$!!

Since he attempted only the $100$ mark test, He got $60$ marks out of $100$!!

Comment: Thank you!  But lets say if the student attempted test A ONLY.

And the grades were ranked as follows:

Test A(20.0%), Test B(25.0%), Test C(30.0%), Test D(25.0%)
Would this still mean he got 60 percent for that specific test A?

Comment: @Alex Yes, the same rule still holds.. regardless of what the other $80\%$ which didn't attempt , is.

Comment: thanks, sorry so you mean that even though he didn't attempt the other 80%, he still received 60% for that test A?

Comment: @Alex Absolutely. He received $60\%$ in that test A